# Calculate the mean of multiple data file along the rows?

Tags: python, numpy

I have multiple data files with two columns each(x,y). Now I want to take the mean of the y column from each dataset and write the mean as a new file. For example y1, y2, y3 are the columns of datasets dat1, dat2, dat3 respectively. Now let says column y has 3 entries y1_a1, y1_a2, y1_a3 and similarly other columns has y2_a1, y2_a2, y2_a3 ....... so on!! I want to calculate the mean along the rows of each columns s.t mean(y1_a1 + y2_a1 + y3_a1). Do someone have any idea how I can do that? Here is my code where I load the data files and split them to there x and y axis.

```py
def plot_data(data):
    xData, yData = np.hsplit(data, 2)
    x = xData[:,0]
    y = yData[:,0]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.title("Graph number {index}".format(index=i))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
for i in range(0, 3):
    data = np.loadtxt('data0{i}.dat')
    plot_data(data)
    plt.legend

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample of the input, and especially a sample of the desired output?

Comment: The input would be like 2D array. The output will be dataset with one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# making up some data 
dat1=pd.DataFrame({"x":["x1","x2","x3","x4"],"y":[24,35,81,99]})
dat2=pd.DataFrame({"x":["x1","x2","x3","x4"],"y":[12,17,1,76]})

# applying mean and converting it into a 1-column dataframe
df_means=pd.DataFrame({"means":[dat1["y"].mean(),dat2["y"].mean()]})
print(df_means)
```

output:

```
   means
0  59.75
1  26.50
```